# Question showing more views. Why?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

My question

[Why did Morpheus tell Trinity to stay off the freeway?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/77950/why-did-morpheus-tell-trinity-to-stay-off-the-freeway)

has been viewed 13900 times. But it's showing 14K views in questions section. Why ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the view counter is obviously just showing the number accurate to the order of thousands in that place (as noticable from the `K`), it's rounding to the nearest multiple of 1,000. It would be rather unfortunate to only make use of the `K`-shortening when it's *exactly* 14,000.

To get the exact number, you just visit the question and look to the top right.